# jQuery, C# and server side data validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I've been using jQuery to post data and was wondering how best to perform server-side validation on the data. I check the values client-side but know it's good practice to also check server-side.

I've searched online but can't really find any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There [are many ways of doing validation server side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx), but to make it easy for you you could use an existing library.

the [Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx) offers a bunch of features that you can use to implement common practices. Validation is one of them. Microsoft Enterprise Library is a collection of application blocks designed to assist developers with common enterprise development challenges.

The Enterprise Library **[Validation Application Block](http://ttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664356%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx)** provides useful features that allow developers to implement structured and easy-to-maintain validation scenarios in their applications.

a great sample is found [at Using Validation Block Attributes to Define Validation Rule Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664716%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx)

more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664356(v=PandP.50).aspx

Comment: Ok the validation blocks seem like a good neat way of doing it.  As im doing the validation clientside and the serverside validation is a double check how would i handle invalid data.  Should i just throw an exception, log it and inform the user there has been an error in the error method of the jquery ajax procedure.

Comment: Note clientSideValidation is not a strong validation, just a user friendly way of telling how to input data. The real job is done on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it manually (ie, `if (model.Value != null)`), or via [data annotations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs)

Comment: yeh i just looked and it seems quite interesting.  shame its only for mvc

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ASP.NET server-side validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx).